# Bias variance tradeoff boosting (xgboost) vs random forest (randomized bagging) which to use when?

Tags: random-forest, xgboost, bias

I was looking up differences between boosting an bagging and I see this quoted everywhere

> If the classifier is unstable (high variance), then we should apply
> Bagging. If the classifier is stable and simple (high bias) then we
> should apply Boosting.

also

> Breiman [1996a] showed that Bagging is effective on ``unstable''
> learning algorithms where small changes in the training set result in
> large changes in predictions. Breiman [1996a] claimed that neural
> networks and decision trees are examples of unstable learning
> algorithms.[check last lines](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume11/opitz99a-html/node3.html)

Aren't gbdt's the most preferred/recommended learners in xgboost ?  Which is contradictory considering how decision trees are apparently unstable learners.

Answer (score 1):

The decision trees used in gradient boosting are typically shallow decision trees (with only a few nodes). Limiting the depth or number of nodes in the decision tree makes them simple. This is different from fully developed decision trees used as standalone models.

Comment: ... and in Random Forests, too.